# how to express when a person put an object (a table, a chair, a bar of wood) down heavily and noisily on the ground?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Ok, in the dictionary

> [stamp](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stamp_2) [transitive, intransitive] stamp (something) to put your foot
>   down heavily and noisily on the ground
>
> I tried stamping my feet to keep warm.
>
> Sam stamped his foot in anger.
>
> He stamped the snow off his boots.
>
> The audience were stamping and cheering.

---

It seems like the verb "**stamp**" is used only with "**foot**".

Could we **creatively** use the structure with other objects such as a table, a chair, etc as in "please, **do not stamp the chair / the table / the wood / the object**"?

If not, **how to express when a person put an object (a table, a chair, a bar of wood) down heavily and noisily on the ground**?

Note: This action is similar to "**stamp**" but "**stamp**" can be used with "**foot**" only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that 'stamp' for this meaning is almost exclusively for the foot, [ignoring the postage/rubber stamp type of meaning, or even mechanical/engineering to press metal into shape, which are vaguely related.*]

You could, with a great deal of force, **slam** an object on the ground, but this is probably a far larger action than you are imagining; you could envisage this as swinging the object from above shoulder-height to give that much force to it.

Instead, I'd think if it was just someone being not careful enough, or even somewhat angry, they'd just **bang** it down.

That would give enough sense of either careless or even intentional action, but the chair would still arrive on the ground upright & intact, just noisily ;)

So, to tell them to stop…

> Hey, stop banging the furniture around!

Whether they take that to mean 'take more care' or 'be less angry' would simply be inferred from the circumstances.

*I'd guess their origins may have been similar, but they have diversified far enough that you cannot stamp a chair, other than to post it.

Comment: I immediately thought of the word "bang".